# What is switch action & forwardAction in struts

Tags: java, struts

What is switch action & forwardAction in struts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a blog post while searching over the net. Here is the [link](http://thinkstruts.blogspot.com/2008/06/advanced-actions-in-struts-difefrences.html).

Comment: thanx for giving me ur precious time and answer .