# Switch action in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts

I'm using Struts, in my project I am having 2 modules (admin, user) "admin" is having different operations like adding users, removing users, adding items, removing users and "user" is having operations like ordering items, checking his account balance.

Now I wanna differentiate user pages and admin pages (i.e. if admin is logged I wanna provide him admin module, if user is logged I wanna provide him user)

I got to know about switch action can be used in this scenario but I don't have any examples in net how to use switch action in Struts 2 (but I am having switch action examples in Struts 1.2 from Google).

Comment: Learn Struts2, use OOP, it's all you need to achieve almost every goal. Never heard of "abt switchaction"...

Comment: switch action has appeared before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/797576/422353

Comment: Ahh, Struts stuff, not Struts2... consider editing the title

Answer (score 0):

In Struts2 the module concept is associated with **namespace**. And it prefixed to any action to distinguish name collisions.

There's plenty examples for login over the net. Once the user login you can keep this information in session. The switch could be done via configuring results but in JSP you should check this session information.

**For example:**

```jsp
<s:if test="#session.loginUser != 'admin'">
  <jsp:forward page="/user/Page.jsp" />  
</s:if>
```

---